# Word Template : Overwrite bookmark Information

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template, when opened opens up a user-form for specified data. But how can I delete the data inputted (bookmarks), if I want to rerun the macro to add new data. Currently it just adds on to whatever is filled.

```
Private Sub Cancelbut_Click()
    PInfo.Hide

End Sub
Private Sub OKbut_Click()
    Dim CompamyName As Range
    Dim CompanyName2 As Range
    Set CompanyName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("CName").Range
    Set CompanyName2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("CName2").Range
    CompanyName.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
    CompanyName2.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value

    Dim VendorName As Range
    Set VendorName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("VName").Range
    VendorName.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value

    Dim ProjectName As Range
    Dim ProjectName2 As Range
    Set ProjectName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PName").Range
    Set ProjectName2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PName2").Range
    ProjectName.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value
    ProjectName2.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value

    Dim ProjectCode As Range
    Set ProjectCode = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PCode").Range
    ProjectCode.Text = Me.TextBox4.Value

    Me.Repaint
    PInfo.Hide

End Sub
```

How would someone go about clearing the existing data? Feel like this would help anyone trying to work with bookmarks in word. I have attempted to do it, but end up deleting the bookmarks.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to a bookmark (whether as a user or using code) deletes the bookmark - this is by-design. When working with VBA, however, you have a work-around not easily available to the user...

If you first assign a `Range` object to the bookmark's Range, the text you assign to the Range can subsequently be bookmarked again. Since you write to numerous bookmarks, best to put these actions into a separate procedure, rather than repeat them throughout your code, as proposed below.

Tip: You can save yourself some code if you put `REF` fields (cross-references) in for the second bookmarks, where you write the information twice.

```
Function WriteToBookmarkRetainBookmark(rng As Object, content As String)
    Dim sBkmName As String

    sBkmName = rng.Bookmarks(1).Name
    rng.Text = content
    rng.Document.Bookmarks.Add sBkmName, rng
End Function

Private Sub OKbut_Click()
    Dim CompamyName As Range
    Dim CompanyName2 As Range

    Set CompanyName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("CName").Range
    Set CompanyName2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("CName2").Range
    WriteToBookmarkRetainBookmark(CompanyName, Me.TextBox1.Value)
    WriteToBookmarkRetainBookmark(CompanyName2, Me.TextBox1.Value)

    Dim VendorName As Range
    Set VendorName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("VName").Range
    WriteToBookmarkRetainBookmark(VendorName, Me.TextBox2.Value)

    Dim ProjectName As Range
    Dim ProjectName2 As Range
    Set ProjectName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PName").Range
    Set ProjectName2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PName2").Range
    WriteToBookmarkRetainBookmark(ProjectName, Me.TextBox3.Value)
    WriteToBookmarkRetainBookmark(ProjectName2, Me.TextBox3.Value)

    Dim ProjectCode As Range
    Set ProjectCode = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("PCode").Range
    WriteToBookmarkRetainBookmark(ProjectCode, Me.TextBox4.Value)

    Me.Repaint
    PInfo.Hide    
End Sub
```

Comment: oh perfect! That makes sense. Thanks